# Default maximum heap size -- Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, openjdk6-jre

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, memory-limit, sun-java6-jdk

I just installed openjdk6-jre on Ubuntu 10.04

java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.2) (6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu1~10.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)

Every time I run "java" I get this error:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

This can be solved by specifying a maximum heap size and running

"java -Xmx256m"

But is there anyway to permanently fix this error (i.e. set the default heap size to 256MB so that I do not need to specify the max heap size every time I run the command)